# why defun is not the same as (setq <name> <lambda>)?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm confused about how defun macro works, because

```
(defun x () "hello")
```

will create function x, but symbol x still will be unbound.

If I'll bind some lambda to x then x will have a value, but it will not be treated by interpreter as function in form like this:

```
(x)
```

I think that it is related to the fact that defun should define function in global environment, but I'm not sure what does it exactly mean. Why can't I shadow it in the current environment?

Is there any way to force interpreter treat symbol as function if some lambda was bound to it? For example:

```
(setq y (lambda () "I want to be a named function"))
(y)
```

P.S.: I'm using SBCL.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Common Lisp has different namespaces for functions and values.

You define functions in the function namespace with `DEFUN`, `FLET`, `LABELS` and some others.

If you want to get a function object as a value, you use `FUNCTION`.

```
(defun foo (x) (1+ x))

(function foo)   ->  #<the function foo>
```

or shorter:

```
#'foo    ->   #<the function foo>
```

If you want to call a function, then you write `(foo 100)`.

If you want to call the function as a value then you need to use `FUNCALL` or `APPLY`:

```
(funcall #'foo 1)
```

You can pass functions around and call them:

```
(defun bar (f arg)
  (funcall f arg arg))

(bar #'+ 2)  ->  4
```

In the case of DEFUN:

It is not `(setf (symbol-value 'FOO) (lambda ...))`.

It is more like `(setf (symbol-function 'foo) (lambda ...))`.

Note that the two namespaces enable you to write:

```
(defun foo (list)
  (list list))

(foo '(1 2 3))  ->  ((1 2 3))
```

There is no conflict between the built-in function `LIST` and the variable `LIST`. Since we have two different namespaces we can use the same name for two different purposes.

Note also that in the case of local functions there is no *symbol* involved. The namespaces are not necessarily tied to symbols. Thus for local variables a function lookup via a symbol name is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

Common Lisp has multiple slots for each symbol, including a value-slot, and a function-slot. When you use the syntax `(x)`, common lisp looks for the function-slot-binding of `x`. If you want to call the value-binding, use `funcall` or `apply`.

See http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/functions.html

Comment: hilarous! and i thought perl was special with $foo, @foo, %foo, foo.

Comment: @Dmitry In the POSIX shell, `$test`, the variable, is unrelated to the `test` command/function.