# How can I modify function bindings in Common Lisp?

Tags: variables, binding, scheme, lisp, common-lisp

Here is something you can do in Scheme:

```
> (define (sum lst acc)
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (sum (cdr lst) (+ acc (car lst)))))
> (define sum-original sum)
> (define (sum-debug lst acc)
    (print lst)
    (print acc)
    (sum-original lst acc))
> (sum '(1 2 3) 0)
6
> (set! sum sum-debug)
> (sum '(1 2 3) 0)
(1 2 3)
0
(2 3)
1
(3)
3
()
6
6
> (set! sum sum-original)
> (sum '(1 2 3) 0)
6
```

If I were to do the following in Common Lisp:

```
> (defun sum (lst acc)
    (if lst
        (sum (cdr lst) (+ acc (car lst)))
        acc))
SUM
> (defvar sum-original #'sum)
SUM-ORIGINAL
> (defun sum-debug (lst acc)
    (print lst)
    (print acc)
    (funcall sum-original lst acc))
SUM-DEBUG
> (sum '(1 2 3) 0)
6
```

Now how can I do something like `(setf sum #'sum-debug)` that would change the binding of a function defined with `defun`?

Comment: While the questions may not (or may) be duplicates , you might find an answer to you question in the answers to some other questions, like [How to store a function in a variable in Lisp and use it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19375270/1281433), [LISP dynamically define functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22975732/1281433), and [why defun is not the same as (setq <name> <lambda>)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11212717/1281433)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Common Lisp has a different namespace for functions, you need to use `symbol-function` or `fdefinition`.

```
CL-USER> (defun foo (a)
           (+ 2 a))
FOO
CL-USER> (defun debug-foo (a)
           (format t " DEBUGGING FOO: ~a" a)
           (+ 2 a))
DEBUG-FOO
CL-USER> (defun debug-foo-again (a)
           (format t " DEBUGGING ANOTHER FOO: ~a" a)
           (+ 2 a))
DEBUG-FOO-AGAIN
CL-USER> (foo 4)
6
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'foo) #'debug-foo)
#<FUNCTION DEBUG-FOO>
CL-USER> (foo 4)
 DEBUGGING FOO: 4
6
CL-USER> (setf (fdefinition 'foo) #'debug-foo-again)
#<FUNCTION DEBUG-FOO-AGAIN>
CL-USER> (foo 4)
 DEBUGGING ANOTHER FOO: 4
6
CL-USER>
```

Comment: [**(setf fdefinition)**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fdefin.htm) can be a little bit more flexible than **(setf fdefinition)** since it works with arbitrary function names, not just symbols.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: What else can be a function name other than a symbol?

Comment: @Matt a list of the form **(setf something)**. you can, e.g., **(defun (setf kar) (value kons) ...)**

Comment: Note that this works in many cases. Exception: when compiled file, the compiler may inline function calls. Then a new definition will not be seen, unless the calling code is recompiled.

Answer (score 5):

A typical use case for redefining functions in such a way is during debugging. Your example indicates that. Common Lisp already provides higher-level machinery for that: `TRACE`. Under the hood it sets the function value of the symbol, but it provides a more convenient user interface. Often something like `TRACE` will have many, non-standard, options.

**Tracing functions**

The following example uses [Clozure Common Lisp](http://ccl.clozure.com), which is always compiling code:

```
? (defun sum (list accumulator)
    (declare (optimize debug))   ; note the debug declaration
    (if (endp list)
        accumulator
        (sum (rest list) (+ accumulator (first list)))))
SUM
? (sum '(1 2 3 4) 0)
10
? (trace sum)
NIL
? (sum '(1 2 3 4) 0)
0> Calling (SUM (1 2 3 4) 0) 
 1> Calling (SUM (2 3 4) 1) 
  2> Calling (SUM (3 4) 3) 
   3> Calling (SUM (4) 6) 
    4> Calling (SUM NIL 10) 
    <4 SUM returned 10
   <3 SUM returned 10
  <2 SUM returned 10
 <1 SUM returned 10
<0 SUM returned 10
10
```

Then to untrace:

```
? (untrace sum)
```

**Advising functions**

In your example you have printed the arguments on entering the function. In many Common Lisp implementations there is another mechanism to augment functions with added functionality: *advising*. Again using Clozure Common Lisp and its `advise` macro:

```
? (advise sum                                 ; the name of the function
          (format t "~%Arglist: ~a" arglist)  ; the code
          :when :before)                      ; where to add the code
#<Compiled-function (CCL::ADVISED 'SUM) (Non-Global)  #x302000D7AC6F>

? (sum '(1 2 3 4) 0)

Arglist: ((1 2 3 4) 0)
Arglist: ((2 3 4) 1)
Arglist: ((3 4) 3)
Arglist: ((4) 6)
Arglist: (NIL 10)
10
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very useful tips! Side question: What's the point of `endp` if it is the same as `not` (or reordering the `if` expression)?

Comment: @Matt: `ENDP` indicates that the argument is a list. `(endp somelist)` vs.  `(null anything)`. Makes reading a code a little bit better and may also signal  an error when `ENDP` is called with something other than a list.